# How to obtain the clicked DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Generically in pure js or jquery, or in the context of rails, how do you obtain the DOM element that was clicked?

Usually you do something like this, allowing you to use `$(this).whatever_method`

```
$(#something).on('click', function()
{
  $(this).do_something;
}_;
```

But in my case, I have a link in my html that is remote: true, and in my controller I render a js.erb file. In such a scenario, all of the javascript code in the js.erb file gets executed. There is no place for a click listener, since the only reason this js.erb file is executing is because something was already clicked. but I do want to select the DOM element that was clicked. How do I do this?

I don't want to simply select it manually, since that is not very dynamic or reusable (plus, I'd have to inject logic to select the right one anyway).

---

**html**

```
<%= link_to "text", send(some_path, @votable, vote_type: "#{s.name}"), remote: true, class: "option" %>
<%= link_to "text", send(some_path, @votable, vote_type: "#{s.name}"), remote: true, class: "option" %>
```

**controller**

```
def action
  render 'shared/vote'
end
```

**/views/shared/vote.js.erb**

```
// how to obtain the link that i clicked in the html file (i.e. the first `".option"` link rather than the second.
// would using `$(this)` here, work? it seems wrong.
```

Comment: what does your back end controller have to do with creating an event listener client side? Post relevant html and explain problem you have in reference to client side source

Comment: because it seems like adding a click listener is redundant in this case. I'm calling a js.erb file to execute upon clicking a link that rails routes to a js.erb file.

Comment: If I was including javascript in the assets folder, then I would add click event listeners, and execute its block of code upon clicking. But in this case, the js.erb file which is a view rendered by the controller executes immediately. I think that would mean adding an event listener is kind of not the right way, right?

Comment: can you pass it as `GET` parameter appended to `some_path`?

Comment: by 'it', you mean a string, or the DOM element itself? Just do a string parse?

Comment: what do you expect to get from the element? Stop and explain your problem from a higher level...so far very little is making sense

Comment: "How to obtain the clicked DOM element?"

pretty self explanatory. I'm explaining as best as i can. I provided the code necessary. If you don't understand, maybe you can clarify what info you want. If you're  going to downvote because you dont' understand the question, then I don't need your help

Comment: not self explanatory at all, what are the differences between 2 elements with same href in your app? Other than GET params there is no way to make a link pass data to server if link is intended to open a new http request using browser default process

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031452/finding-which-element-is-clicked-in-the-dom

I know the concept is possible. But I can't make sense of that answer. and I suspected i needed rails-specific info in my case, which is why i didn't comment on that qusetion to "please explain the code for me"

Comment: I was originally thinking it have been possible to use selectors, or listening to the entire DOM somehow, to obtain which element was clicked or fired off certain event. I don't know the deeper side of javascript to know what methods to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ajax**

Even if you're using `remote: true`, there is still room for a `click` listener. You'll probably be best using the [ajax hooks](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) with the element that initiates the remote ajax call:

```
$(document").on("ajax:beforeSend", "#your_element", function(){
   $(this).hide(); -> hides element
});
```

I think you'll be able to use this over the `.click` event binder in your example. Reason being, although you *can* call `click`, it will essentially not have any bearing on the `ajax` call; whilst using one of the `ajax hooks` will have some bearing on it

--

**Rails**

In regards to your Rails backend (your `.js.erb` file), you simply won't be able to reference `$(this)` with that part of your application. Reason being JS works with the [`DOM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) - meaning it can only observe both the elements on the screen *and* those within the correct function scope

If you want to interact with the links directly, you should look at using one of the ajax hooks I mentioned above, with page interactivity being provided by the backend `.js.erb` file mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your way of thinking is a bit wrong because js.erb will be executed after a new request is sent to server, so you won't be able to link it with current DOM element.

In order to accomplish your goal, I think you should assign each link a unique ID and then pass that ID to the server along with the request params. And then on your js.erb, you will be able to use that ID to correctly identify the link has been clicked.

Ex:

```
<%= link_to "Test link", some_path(link_id: "link_1"), remote: true, id: "link_1" %>

<%= link_to "Test link 2", some_path(link_id: "link_2"), remote: true, id: "link_2" %>
```

Controller

```
def my_action
    @link_id = params[:link_id]
end
```

js.erb

```
console.log($("#<%= @link_id %>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Vanilla JavaScript `this` within the callback function to the `addEventListener` function is the element that has triggered the event.

Please refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/4hwLb/)

Markup:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button" />
```

JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(this);
})
```

[image: demo(gig)]

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: so your adding `addEventListener` is not necessary if you're just trying to manipulate the obtained object, correct? This script in my case is executing after i click a normal link that i told rails to call a javascript file upon clicking.

Comment: when a js.erb file is rendered by rails, the code inside executes immediately. is it right to add an event listener when the entire file is already set to execute?

Comment: I am not sure if I comprehend your concerns.

Comment: does it not matter if the link is already set to execute via ajax by the framework? do you simply add an event listener, even if it's already a link, and the server rendered another file/template? why would it not be redundant or not be ignored? I'm thinking if the controller renders this js.erb file, and we have an event listener, we would need to click the link again in order to fire off the code within the event listener block. is this not the case? clearly i'd want it to execute the code block by clicking once, not twice.

Comment: i tried adding an event click listener. it would not work. I think this is because it is as i suspected. rendering a js.erb file is set to execute. But if i add a listener in this file, it expects me to click it again before executing the block code, rather than executing immediately. When i click it again, the rails behavior takes over and renders this file again, instead oif triggering the block code of the event listener.