# disable <li> element upon click

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have an events function `'click .category'` that is called whenever the `<li class="category">` is clicked on. It is an element in a dropdown list, specifically one from Bootstrap. I am really stuck on how to disable that element by adding the `'disabled'` class to the `<li>`. I know in jQuery you would just execute a simple function like `.addClass`. Is there a way in Meteor/Blaze to accomplish this?

Comment: Meteor includes jQuery and depends on it for manipulating it the DOM so just go ahead and do the normal `$('.category').addClass('disabled')` in your event handler.

Comment: jQuery is already loaded with meteor, so why not use it? If you really want to go through some hassle, you could set a helper that would set the class as in `<li class="{{your_helper}}">`. There are numerous ways you could implement this, but again, jQuery is lightweight and already loaded by default.

Comment: oh I thought it better convention to use Meteor's tools. I'll go ahead and use it then!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like the below?

```
Template.myTemplateName.events({
  "click .category": function(event, template){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.category').addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah i have, and it didn't work. I realized that there were multiple elements with class `'category'`, so maybe that was the reason why I couldn't disable anything? I ended up having to use an id to get it to work, but I am still exploring options, because having 10-15 different ids just for this feature seems kinda absurd. Is there an easy way to target the current class `event` is in? I tried `event.currentTarget` to no avail.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031452/finding-which-element-is-clicked-in-the-dom) might help:

Answer (score -1):

Here is the standard Meteor way of achieving this using a `ReactiveVar`.

HTML

```
<template name="category">
  <li class="category {{disabled}}">
    {{! category HTML}}
  </li>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.category.onCreated(function(){
  this.disabled = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.category.helpers({
  disabled: function(){
    var disabled = Template.instance().disabled.get();
    return disabled ? "disabled" : "";
  }
});


Template.category.events({
  "click .category": function(event, template){
    var disabled = template.disabled.get();
    template.disabled.set(!disabled);
  }
});
```

It's always better to let the Meteor templates rendering engine (Blaze) manipulate the DOM for you. Using template instances lets you easily write reusable components.

Comment: That's not standard, that's just complicated.